# Function not working after certain line: Pylint says "Unreacheable Code"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply a function to several files, but I'm not getting output at all from the function, and pylint says the code is unreacheable.

This is my current code:

```
path = str(askdirectory())

for metric in metrics:
    corner = pd.read_excel(f'{path}/{metric} - TOP LEFT CELL.xlsx')
    metricFrame(corner)
```

Up until this point the code works properly but it doesn't do anything inside the function:

```
def metricFrame(corner,top,left,filling): 

    # # Extract Top Left Corner Metric from TOP LEFT files  
    topleft = corner.iloc[0]['A']    
    return topleft 
    print(corner) # This is the line that pylint highlights as unreacheable
```

The 'return' is causing the function to stop running or breaking? why does this happen?

Comment: paste the print before return

Comment: Yes, `return` will be the last statement executed in the function. That's what it does.

Comment: `return` "returns" the value of a function, therefore ending it.

Comment: It will never reach the code and pylint is hinting correctly here. The interpreter will never be able to reach the code `print(corner)` as you are returning earlier than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `print(corner)` ahead of `return topleft`. A `return` call ends the function.

Answer (score 1):

`return` exits the function. Put the `print()` statement before `return`